# How can I prevent a parent div from growing with its children?

Tags: css, position

I have a `ul` inside of a `div`, and want the containing `div` to not be affected by the child `ul` in terms of height.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9eCq6/3/

Referring to the jsfiddle, I'd like the yellow `div` to not be any taller than the blue `divs`, and for the block of text below the colored `divs` to not be pushed down by the red `ul` - that is, I'd like it to overlap the block of text below.

I suspect the answer lies in positioning and is affected by the floats being applied, but I haven't been able to find the solution yet. What should I do, or read, to find the solution?

Edit: I want to not give the parent a fixed height, because I don't know what content might get added to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use absolute positioning to breakaway from parent. Also you will need `overflow: visible` and a clearfix:

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
}

.wrap::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.right ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: This does keep from pushing down the div below, but the yellow background div still grows with the ul. Do you know how to prevent that?

Comment: That seems perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[This old BrainJar article](http://www.brainjar.com/css/positioning/) is a great, thorough reference on CSS positioning. It is absolutely dated, but holds up surprisingly well. You will run into these sorts of issues *far* less often if you spend the time first to get a solid understanding of the underlying systems you're dealing with.

That said, a (partial) solution to your problem is straightforward. Put the `div.under` inside the `div.wrap`, and add `clear: left;` to the CSS `.under` selector. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yYYp6/).

Answer (score -2):

Give the parent fixed size, and use `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified I want to avoid a fixed height for the parent, because I don't know what content might get added to it.

Comment: Those are conflicting requirements.